# Encryption of string in Android SDK

Tags: php, android

I need to encrypt String & send to sever which is in php.

Below you will find encryption code and function to encrypt it.

```
define('SALT', 'whateveryouwant'); 

function encrypt($text) 
{ 
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT,
$text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB),
MCRYPT_RAND)))); 
} 

function decrypt($text) 
{ 
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT,
base64_decode($text), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB),
MCRYPT_RAND))); 

}
```

I tried out some classes in android but did not work at all.
Anybody having idea about the functions or classes in android which support this functionality?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Android has [`javax.crypto`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) package for this purpose.

Take a look at an example [code for encrypting a string](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/DesString.html). Also useful is [code to list all available cyphers](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/ListCipher.html).